# mod_rewrite: how to point to a different file but keep the query vars?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these rewriteRules which work fine:

```
# 4 params
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&do=$2&what=$3&id=$4 [NC,L,QSA]

# 3 params
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&do=$2&what=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

# 2 params
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&do=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# 1 param
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now, i would like that if the url contains `/api/` then i would like it to point to a file called `public.api.php` but still have those 4 query vars as parameters.
I could arrange that via explicitating all the rules in the order in which they should be processed, but it makes for a quite lengthy .htaccess file.

My questions is this: is there a way to add some sort of conditional rule that would check if `/api/` is in the requested uri and according to this, point to `index.php` or `public.api.php` without repeating the processing of the four query vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be if you just add some rules like:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ public.api.php?app=$1&do=$2&what=$3&id=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ public.api.php?app=$1&do=$2&what=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ public.api.php?app=$1&do=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ public.api.php?app=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**Edit**    Here’s another approach:

```
RewriteRule (^|.+?/)api/?([^/].*)?$ $1$2

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&do=$2&what=$3&id=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&do=$2&what=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&do=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^?\ ]+/)?api/?
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ public.api.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the ? and capture all params as one group?

```
RewriteRule ^.*/api/.*\?(.*)$ /public.api.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: could you elaborate? I'm not sure i understand the logic you propose.

Comment: Just copy over every request parameter, all matched in one group, like sketched in that RewriteRule above, which admittedly is not really tested.

Comment: Your regexp all don't escape the ? which means "any character one time" in regexp-ish.

Comment: This won’t work as the URL query is not part of the URL path.